# Problems getting desired output from SQL JOIN Query

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

Trying to extract data from multiple SQL tables. I have a main table and a couple of sub-tables. I want to get all the rows from the main table given a condition and add some fields from the sub-tables. I figured an `OUTER JOIN` should have worked but I am not getting the entire data.

When I run a `COUNT` on the main table with the condition I get ~10k rows which is what I am expecting to get once I join the other tables. I understand that I will get NULL values on some row entries.

This is the query I came up with but I am only getting partial results

```
SELECT main_table.group_id, main_table.floor, sub_table1.Name, sub_table2.base
FROM main_table
LEFT JOIN ON main_table.group_id =sub_table1.group_id
LEFT JOIN ON main_table.group_id =sub_table2.group_id
WHERE main_table.year = 2000 AND sub_table1.year = 2000 
AND sub_table2.year = 2000 AND main_table.group = 'C'
```

I am expecting to see a collection of about 10k rows since that is the number I get when only querying the main table with where clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM main_table WHERE year = 2000 AND group = 'C';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `where` clause is filtering out the extra rows from the outer joins -- effectively turning them into inner joins.

Conditions on all but the first table should be in the `on` clauses.  But I would phrase this as:

```
SELECT main_table.group_id, main_table.floor, sub_table1.Name, sub_table2.base
FROM main_table LEFT JOIN
     sub_table1
     ON main_table.group_id = sub_table1.group_id AND
        main_table.year = sub_table1.year LEFT JOIN
     sub_table2
     ON main_table.group_id = sub_table2.group_id AND
        main_table.year = sub_table2.year
WHERE main_table.year = 2000 AND main_table.group = 'C';
```

You want the `year`s to be equal, so that should really be a `JOIN` condition.  Then you only need to specify the year once in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Is there are a reason why I would get duplicates on this query? I am getting ~2k values over the expected outcome.

Comment: @itms . . . You would get duplicates if multiples rows in the tables match the `join` conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever condition in `ON` clause is used for join and condition in `WHERE` clause are used to filter out final result.

Apart from gordon's answer, If your requirement is to include different/same years in joins then you can use following query:

```
SELECT main_table.group_id, main_table.floor, sub_table1.Name, sub_table2.base
FROM main_table LEFT JOIN
     sub_table1
     ON (main_table.group_id = sub_table1.group_id AND
        sub_table1.year = 2000) LEFT JOIN
     sub_table2
     ON (main_table.group_id = sub_table2.group_id AND
        sub_table2.year = 2000)
WHERE main_table.year = 2000 AND main_table.group = 'C';
```

Cheers!!